# Too frequent security alert from Google due to "Unrecognised device" on Angular 7 web app

Tags: google-oauth

I am developer and maintainer of an Angular web app which uses Google OAuth. This works normally.

Last week the app users (me including) started receiving standard Security alert emails from Google (no-reply@accounts.google.com) on a daily basis. The Email says "Appname was granted access to your Google account". This is of course bad signal to the users.

When clicked on "Check Activity" in the Email it always says:
Unrecognised device
X hours ago
Unknown (location)

This is the case for all users tested on many different devices and IPs.

Recently I have upgraded from Angular 5 to Angular 7 if that might help.

Also recently I noticed absolutely the same behaviour when I sign-in to Dropbox using a Gmail. The application I am responsible for is not storing session data for privacy reasons so the users are asked to Sign-in with Google every time they want to use the app. I noticed this behaviour just a week ago (devices and locations not recognised) by Google. 
The google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/oauth2-dev) redirected me to Stackoverflow. Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: This is probably part of Googles crack down on apps with access to user data.  I will ping the team with your question but i would be willing to be everything is working as it should.   Users should be informed when new applications or devices have access to their data.

Comment: Thank you very much @DalmTo . Yes, I totally agree. In my case the frequency of the emails caused by the "unrecognized device/location" issue was bothering me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are sending notifications to users when they approve certain scopes. That list is expanding and more apps will see the notification.
Thanks for the feedback. Looks like the unrecognized device was an issue and we have rolled back that experiment.

Ideally an app should see the notification only once and for non basic scopes (basic scopes being email, profile etc).

Comment: where is the list of the certain scopes which triggers the notifications? could you link the url to the related documentation? thx in advance

Comment: I understand, thank you for the clarification nvnagr! And of course a related documentation would be nice in case those triggers are meant to be open to the public.

Comment: @nvnagr , on the topic of "unrecognized device", is it necessary that I clear my cache or do something specific from my side in order to see the rolled-back stable version that recognize my device and location? Unfortunately me and app users still get notifications every day (once on each first log-in for the day). Thanks for your time!

Comment: @IvanPetrov Are you still seeing the issue? If yes, can you please email me your clientid?

Comment: @nvnagr thank you for your help, the issue is gone, I do not see it anymore!